# How do I relate a relational key from one model to many others? DTO? View model? or list? ASP.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-relationship

Currently the user can add a single ingredient to a recipe, but that relational key is then bound to that one recipe, changing it to a new recipe, removes the old link.

I am looking for a method so a single version of each ingredient exists, but any recipe can contain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have separate `Recipe`, `Ingredient`, and `RecipeIngredient` tables.

```
Ingredient
----------
IngredientID <-- PK
Name
...


Recipe
------
RecipeID <-- PK
Name
...


RecipeIngredient 
----------------
RecipeID     <-- PK
IngredientID <-- PK
```

This is basic [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: But then isn't the ingredient relational key bound to the one recipeIngredient relational key and then unable to interact with another recipeIngredient?

Comment: @GenericController No, the PK on the `RecipeIngredient` intersection table is a compound key of both `RecipeID` and `IngredientID`, meaning one recipe can have many ingredients and each ingredient can be in more than one recipe. I have updated the schema to make the keys more clear.

Comment: @RedFiler - I appreciate the help, currently underway with implementing this. 
From my perspective it feels like a lot of 'smoke and mirrors' is occurring in these ASP.net situations, I find it hard to see the intuitive result.

Thanks RedFilter.

Comment: @RedFiler - Do I add ingredientDetails to recipe with a collection of ingredients, and then add a new ingredientRecipe to the recipe with associate ingredients with it. Or is ingredientDetails an entity that exists to direct the PK data between the ingredient and multiple recipes?

Comment: This is the first you have mentioned of `ingredientDetails`, I have no idea where it fits in...

Comment: Sorry it has been a long day, I meant to say RecipeIngredient instead of ingredientDetails.

So to rephrase:

Do I add RecipeIngredients(which contains a collection of Ingredients) to Recipe, or is RecipeIngredients used primarly as a set of relational keys to link Recipe and Ingredients?

Comment: The latter. When adding a new recipe you create a `Recipe` record, and then use the resulting `RecipeID` to populate `RecipeIngredient` with the corresponding `IngredientID` numbers. If the ingredients don't alreay exist in the `Ingredient` table, you would add those first, so that you get the resulting `IngredientIDs`, and then do the insert into `RecipeIngredient`.

Comment: @RedFiler - I appreciate your extended help with me on this issue. I am using ASP.net for this project, so I am having to concede to its oddities. I still fail to achieve this. I have an Icollection of RecipeIngredients in Recipe, that contains the recipeID for the Recipe it is to associate with and the ingredientID for the ingredient to associate with. I have supplied two images that depict my context initializer and how I associate the keys, and the content of my models. http://imgur.com/a/sIYJ6

Comment: @GenericController I am not sure what your issue is, but it sounds unrelated to your question above. I recommend you create a new question.